# constructor Point(double, double) is undefined

Tags: java, constructor, point

When I build this method, I get constructor Point(double, double) is undefined. But when I type cast the variables delta, deltaX, deltaY, the error goes away. What am I doing wrong here? I have the Point library imported in this Line class and all my setters and getters set as doubles as well.

```
public Point solve(Line line2)
{
    double delta = this.a * line2.getB() - this.b * line2.getA();
    double deltaX = this.c * line2.getB() - this.b * line2.getC();
    double deltaY = this.a * line2.getC() - this.c * line2.getA();
    
    return new Point(deltaX/delta, deltaY/delta);
    
}
```

Comment: Provide both versions and clearly delineate which one compiles.

Comment: "I have the Point library imported" From where? There are about 100 implementations this could possibly be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Point.html) only has `int` and `Point` constructors.

[Point2D.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) probably does what you want.

Comment: Ah! That is what is was! Thank you oh wise person.